# Named Credential - determining if Named Principal is authenticated?

Tags: apex, oauth2, namedcredentials

I'm using Named Credentials to support a Scheduled Apex job that needs to call into the Salesforce REST API. The Named Credential is of type Named Principal, using Oauth, and it works just fine.

Here's my question: is there any way for my Apex code to determine whether this credential currently has a valid authentication status and, if not, prompt the user to authenticate? I'm wondering about the deployment process for this application to my production instance - do I need to manually authorize the named credential as part of my deployment process, or can I account for this in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your environment changed when you move to production, you need to do a manual step to authorize the user used for the integration. With Named credential, after you deploy it , use the `Start Authentication Flow on Save` option to authorize the user.
[image]

As for Oauth you would be using access token for the integration. Reading this might be helpful - [OAuth Access Token Expiration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73512/oauth-access-token-expiration)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this by an error handling in the catch block. Once, we marked this as a post-deployment step to authenticate the named credential whose identity type is 'named principal' with a user having the admin profile.

Comment: I don't understand how a catch block can be a post-deployment step. (What Exception would you catch anyway?)

Comment: I mean, eventually, it is a manual step. Putting it in a catch block is a separate topic. You can notify the user by creating a toast message or an error log record on the UI.