# Verify if Named Credential is live

Tags: apex, namedcredentials

Is there a way in Apex to verify if a Named Credential is live, so to speak? Of course, I can hit the endpoint and check the status code, but I'm looking for a more native approach. Specifically, is there a way to access the `Authentication Status` field from Apex or through Metadata/Tooling API?

The question is similar to [this SFSE post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178542/named-credential-determining-if-named-principal-is-authenticated) but with different reasoning. The Authentication Protocol may be anything, and I'm looking to display the connection status on a custom component.

Comment: Calling out is the only way, unfortunately. A backup option that's sort of native is using a UI automation framework (e.g. Selenium-based) and calling it from Javascript.