# Token access expiry time and how to expire token forcefully

Tags: salesforce1-app, rest

Is it possible to know how much is the time limit of a access token for a connected Org. As till the extent I know it is equal to your activity on connected app or timelimit set in Setup -> Administration Setup -> Security Controls -> Session Settings > Timeout value.

As if its the same is there any possibility to forcefully expire a token after sometime with the help of salesforce setting or some paramter that can be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Is it possible to know how much is the time limit of a access token for a connected Org**

Answer is **[No](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73512/oauth-access-token-expiration)** except you hit salesforce endpoint using access token and if you get 4xx as response it means token got expired and you can call refresh token to get new token.

**2. Forcefully expire token**

To revoke OAuth 2.0 tokens (access/refresh), use the revocation endpoint.

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/revoke
```

Construct a POST request that includes the following parameters using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format in the HTTP request entity-body. For example:

```
    POST /revoke HTTP/1.1
    Host: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/revoke 
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    token=currenttoken
```

If an access token is included, Salesforce invalidates it and revokes the token. If a refresh token is included, Salesforce revokes it and any associated access tokens.

You can also invoke using GET request with parameter token

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/revoke?token=currenttokenID
```

Documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/11/revoking-oauth-2-0-access-tokens-and-refresh-tokens.html)