# How can I programmatically find out when an accessToken expires with the OAuth Token Refresh Flow

Tags: oauth2, refresh-token

My company is using the [OAuth "Refresh Token" flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5), and can get an accessToken and refreshToken fine using this flow.

The problem I'm having is that the responses we receive from Salesforce don't have an `exp` field in them, so we don't know how long an accessToken lives for.

```
{  
   "id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00Dx0000000BV7z/005x00000012Q9P",
   "issued_at":"1278448384422",
   "instance_url":"https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/",
   "signature":"SSSbLO/gBhmmyNUvN18ODBDFYHzakxOMgqYtu+hDPsc=",
   "access_token":"someValue",
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "scope":"id api refresh_token"
}
```

**Is there a way to find out how long the accessToken lives for?**

We can change our request of course to include different scopes if need be.

Note that I've noticed that [there's a beta endpoint](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oidc_token_introspection.htm&type=5) that lets you request this information, but it feels to me like something that should be returned with the `accessToken` and `refreshToken`.

Comment: I think this answer is still applicable:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73512/oauth-access-token-expiration

Comment: One way could be to calculate using `issued_at`. A token will live for the duration specified in the session settings. So as long as you have the `issued_at` available and you know the session settings duration, you can calculate the token's lifespan.

Comment: Access tokens automatically update their expiration if at least half the time has passed since issue and it is used in any API call. Also, a user or admin might terminate the session at any time. It is a lot more efficient to build a framework that expects any given call to potentially fail.